# How is the number of "people chatting" computed?

Tags: support, bug, chat, sidebar

The Music Fans chat is pretty lonely, but the system doesn't seem to think so:

> [image: screenshot of chat sidebar]
>
> <sup>Image: *Chat sidebar claims that there are "66 people chatting"*</sup>

On a good day, there are probably 3 people in all the Music Fans chatrooms combined. Yet, the number of people chatting as shown in the sidebar is always in the 60 – 80 range.

What accounts for this discrepancy? How does the system calculate the number of people chatting, and why does it do such a poor job of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the total number of people chatting on the https://chat.stackexchange.com server, which is a shared chat server among (almost) all Stack Exchange sites. These users are mostly chatting in chatrooms associated to other sites than MusicFans.SE. Right now, I'm seeing the same number (more or less) in the sidebar widget on other sites in the network; this screenshot was taken on Puzzling.Meta:

[image]

You see it's a bit more populated than Music Fans chats, but not *that* much.

Note that Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange have their own chat servers, https://chat.stackoverflow.com/ and https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/.